How does pitch accent of a noun change if it comes after an adjective?
Providing the following examples with pitch accents:

新しい車 - drops on し and then goes up on る again
青い車 - drops on お and doesn't go up
小さい車 - drops on さ and doesn't go up
綺麗な車 - drops on き and doesn't go up

I can't see the pattern here, why sometimes the pitch stays low, and sometimes it comes back up? I expected it to go up every time as 車 is a heiban
Is there some kind of rule when combining adjectives with nouns?

First off, a word of warning: OJAD's prosody tutor (aka "Suzuki-kun", which I see is what you used to check for the pitch here) is trash. By which I mean, it's not that bad, but it's limited and unreliable. Trusting its results, or taking them as the only possible option, is often a recipe for confusion. You're honestly better off staying away from it completely, and just relying on your ears instead.
Whether you stay low or rise back up for 車 in your examples (or in any other sentence) is a matter of intonation, not pitch accent, so there is no clear-cut rule or pattern. It depends on context (most notably, whether there's, like, an accented particle attached onto 車) and delivery.
This is generally true for rises in the standard dialect: they're not part of the word's inherent accent, and aren't set in stone. Their presence (or lack thereof) is not an essential feature of the word (← really good vid btw). The defining characteristic of a word's accent is the downstep (＼). In fact, the downstep is often referred to as the accent itself (and it's said to accent the preceding mora).
The only real way to learn intonation is to get a feel for it through lots and lots of careful listening. Keep in mind: ear training is a prerequisite for this, to make sure that you're hearing/processing things correctly. You can train your ears by taking perception tests and getting corrections on your own pitch. For more info on this, I highly recommend watching Strategies for Acquiring Pitch Accent in Japanese. (Strictly speaking, the point of this training is to train your ears for pitch accent, not intonation, but learning to properly hear PA goes hand-in-hand with learning to properly hear intonation, because intonation is a layer of prosody that's applied on top of PA.)
That said, Darius has left a bit of relevant wisdom over at this question and this reddit thread (read also his replies to other comments!), which might help you orient yourself & give you a leg up on how this whole thing works.


新しい車 - drops on し and then goes up on る again

What is your source for this?
A search on youglish  leads me to believe that the accent does indeed stay flat for all three mora (which sounds correct to me as well).

https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/phrasing/index

I may be wrong so take this with a grain of salt.
Generally speaking in neutral speach for adjective + noun combinations if the adjective is said with an accent then the following noun attaches using its original PA pattern but is realized in some sort of weaker (in terms of pitch) way.
If both are accented then the accented noun's slight rise at the beginning of the word may be realized in a weaker way or be mostly absent, while the drop is usually made just weaker.
If the adjective is accented but the noun is heiban, the noun usually attaches directly onto the low pitch from the accented adjective and either slightly rises at the beginning (of the noun) and remain flat or attach to the accented adjective in the same way but remain flat without the slight rise.
If the adjective is heiban then regardless of the noun's PA the noun attaches directly to the high pitch of the adjective then either remains flat in the case of heiban or experiences its downstep according to its PA pattern.
This is just my conjecture for neutral speach. When factoring in sentence level intonation and emphasis, the degree of change for pitch and its location can vary. Also this is just my observation so this is likely wrong in some places.
